# AWS: what is bucket name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buckets

I want to setup CodeDeploy from AWS and I'm following this guide:

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install.html#codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux
```

What is `bucket-name`?
As I can see some `bucket`, but how will I be able to download something from this? I'm talking about this command:

```
wget https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
```

Answer (score 1):

The document there states as follows

> bucket-name represents one of the following:
>
> aws-codedeploy-us-east-2 for instances in the US East (Ohio) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-us-east-1 for instances in the US East (N. Virginia) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-us-west-1 for instances in the US West (N. California) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 for instances in the US West (Oregon) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ca-central-1 for instances in the Canada (Central) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1 for instances in the EU (Ireland) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-eu-west-2 for instances in the EU (London) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1 for instances in the EU (Frankfurt) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Tokyo) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ap-northeast-2 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Seoul) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Singapore) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ap-southeast-2 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Sydney) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-ap-south-1 for instances in the Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region
>
> aws-codedeploy-sa-east-1 for instances in the South America (São Paulo) region

So just check your region and accordingly select the bucket name

E.g. If your region is `US East (N. Virginia)` region then the bucket name is `aws-codedeploy-us-east-1` and accordingly the wget URL is `https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install`